# Nested query in Mongo not working in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, callback

I have some trouble making queries inside a callback running in Meteor Mongo. Anyone is seeing what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

```js
    var houseInserted = Houses.insert({
               building_number: address.building_number,

              },function(error, results){
                   if(error) throw error;
               console.log(results); // runs

               Meteor.users.update( { _id: this.userId },  // Does not execute
                  { $set: { 'profile.housed': true , 'profile.address' : results }
                }, function(err, doc){
                  if (err) throw err; 
                  console.log(results); // runs
                  console.log(doc);
                });
               console.log(results); // runs
              }   
            );
```

Comment: Looks more or less right to me.

Comment: My user collection does not update correctly on mongo and the doc returns 0. The only way to have it working it to take the user update query from the callback.

Comment: Is `this.userId` defined in the insert callback ? I'm not sure. Try Meteor.userId() instead. Also you don't need to pass an object like `{_id: userId}`, you can just pass the `userId` string when querying on an ID.